# How to add to Login PHP script USERNAME and PASSWORD from MYSQL

Tags: php

i'd love to ask you for help i am making a simple Login using Switch Case

Here is my code of my current Login function that works but datas are from config.php .

```
function login() {
  if ( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) {
    if ($_POST['username'] == ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] == ADMIN_PASSWORD) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];
      header( "Location: admin.php" );
    } else {
      $results['errorMessage'] = "Wrong PW or ID";
      require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
    }
  } else {
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
  }
}
?>
```

So i made this method

```
public function login($username,$password) {
        $this->result = Database::ask('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table2.' where username = ? AND password = ?', array($username, $password));
        $this->print = $this->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $this->print;
    }
```

Database class

```
class Database {

    private static $connect;

    private static $set = Array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
    );

    public static function connectDB() {
        if (!isset(self::$connect)) {
            self::$connect = @new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
                self::$set;

        }
        return self::$connect;
    }

    public static function ask($sql, $params= array()) {
        $ask = self::$connect->prepare($sql);
        $ask->execute($params);
        return $ask;
    }

}
```

So i ended up with

```
    function login() {
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $row = new AdministrationDatabaze();
        $loginArray = $row->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

        if(!empty($loginArray['username']) AND !empty($loginArray['password'])){
            $_SESSION['username'] = $loginArray['username'];
            header( "Location: admin.php" );
        }   
        else {
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
    }
  }else {
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
    } 
}
```

But i get -> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in classes/Databaze.php on line 26

Line 26:

```
$ask = self::$connect->prepare($sql);
```

I'd love to know where is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

M.

Comment: Your connection failed. Stop suppressing errors with `@new` and figure out why.

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. You should use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Your issue is in here `self::$connect = @new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );` the connection is not happening giving null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a try/catch block to detect if the connection failed.

```
public static function connectDB() {
    if ( empty(self::$connect) ) {
        try {
            self::$connect = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return self::$connect;
}
```

Call the connectDB function.

```
public function login($username,$password) {
    if ( ! Database::connectDB() ) return null;
    $this->result = Database::ask('SELECT * FROM '.$this->table2.' where username = ? AND password = ?', array($username, $password));
    $this->print = $this->result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $this->print;
}
```

Change the ask function as follows:

```
public static function ask($sql, $params= array()) {
    if ( empty(self::$connect) ) return null;
    $ask = self::$connect->prepare($sql);
    $ask->execute($params);
    return $ask;
}
```

Modify the login function.

```
function login() {
    if ( isset($_POST['login']) ) {
        $row = new AdministrationDatabaze();
        $loginArray = $row->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
        if ( ! $loginArray ) {
            // If there is no login info
            // Maybe you should tell the user that something went wrong.
            require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
        }
        elseif ( ! empty($loginArray['username']) AND ! empty($loginArray['password']) ) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $loginArray['username'];
            header( "Location: admin.php" );
        }   
        else {
            require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
        }
    } else {
        require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that helped a lot. Working now